# fetchone vs fetchone[0] in python sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, exception, sqliteexception

I have a function like the below to get data from SQLite3 table.

```py
def remedysql(crop, disease):
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect('plant_protection.db')
        mycur = conn.cursor()
        sql=f'select remedy from pp_remedy WHERE crop="{crop}" and disease="{disease}"'
        #remedy = mycur.execute(sql).fetchone()[0]
        mycur.execute(sql)
        remedy = mycur.fetchone()[0]
        return remedy
    except sqlite3.Error as error:
        print("Error while connecting to sqlite plantprot DB")
```

For the combination of "crop" and "disease", there will only be one record or none. The above function works fine when I give `fetchone()[0]`, but does not work when I give only `fetchone()` without `[0]`.

Also please advise how to handle the `NoneType` (no record) exception here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone):

> **fetchone()**
>
> Fetches the next row of a query result set, returning a single sequence, or `None` when no more data is available.

The return value is a tuple, so `remedy` will be found at the first element, i.e. `fetchone()[0]`. In the case where the query returns `None`, there is no 0th element, so program will give a TypeError.

One solution would be to use `fetchone()` and make sure it has returned a row before accessing the index. E.G.

```
remedy = mycur.fetchone()
if remedy:
    return remedy[0]
else:
    return None
```

Comment: Thank you! Later I handled this problem with try: and except TypeError. But the suggestion that you have given here is  simple and working perfectly.